# GLM prediction in r

Tags: r, prediction, glm, confidence-interval

I spilt the data set into train and test as following:

```
splitdata<-split(sb[1:nrow(sb),], sample(rep(1:2, as.integer(nrow(sb)/2))))
test<-splitdata[[1]]
train<-rbind(splitdata[[2]])
```

sb is the name of original data set, so it is 50/50 train and test.

Then I fitted a glm using the training set.

```
fitglm<-  glm(num_claims~year+vt+va+public+pri_bil+persist+penalty_pts+num_veh+num_drivers+married+gender+driver_age+credit+col_ded+car_den, family=poisson, train)
```

now I want to predict using this glm, say the next 10 observations.

I have trouble to specify the newdata in predict(),

I tried:

```
pred<-predict(fitglm,newdata=data.frame(train),type="response", se.fit=T)
```

this will give a number of predictions that is equal to the number of samples in training set.

and finally, how to plot these predictions with confidence intervals?

Thank you for the help

Comment: A reproducible example http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 would be strongly preferred. Also, you say what you tried, but you don't say what went wrong: did you get an error (if so, what was it)?  Were the results wrong/not what you expected (if so, how do you know)?

Comment: + you do mean to `predict` on the `test` not `train` data I presume? and what do you mean by "the next 10 observations"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking how to construct predictions on the next 10 in the test set then:

```
pred10<-predict(fitglm,newdata=data.frame(test)[1:10, ], type="response", se.fit=T)
```

Edit 9 years later:

@carsten's comment is correct regarding how to construct a confidence interval. If one has a non-linear link function for a glm-object, `fitglm` then this is a reasonably general method to recover the inverse of the link function and construct a two-sided 95% CI on the response scale:

```
pred.fit <- predict(fitglm, newdata=newdata, se.fit=TRUE)
pred.fit <- predict(fitglm, newdata=newdata, se.fit=TRUE)
CI.pred.upper <- family(fitglm)$linkinv(  # that information is in the model 
                        pred.fit+  1.96*pred.fit$se.fit )

CI.pred.lower <- family(fitglm)$linkinv(  # that information is in the model
                        pred.fit$fit - 1.96*pred.fit$se.fit )
```

Comment: This answer is, regrettably, wrong. In the GLM assuming a Poisson distribution induces a log-link. The standard error is (approximately) normally distributed at the link scale. Back-transformation will thus lead to asymmetric standard errors. With the code presented here, this is not the case. Calling "type='response'" **and** 'se.fit=T' thus cannot be right. The correct way is to omit the "type" argument (or set it to 'link') and get the SE at the link scale. Then add/substract these to/from the estimate (preds$fit +/- 2*preds$se.fit) and backtransform those to get the CIs.

Comment: It Is not wrong, so much as incomplete and possibly misleading. That method does give the predictions which is what was being claimed. It is not giving confidence intervals which was admittedly also being asked. I agree with you method of calculating the CI's.